# How to internationalize DropDownList items using Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

We are working on an MVC website where some list have user and system values. So, system items need to be internationalized to display in the user language, and user items are already in the user language.

Those system items have a flag called "`IsSystem`" to differenciate the ones we need to internationalize. This flag also mean that the user cannot update or delete those items.

Well, we are using `@Html.DropDownList` to render this DropDownList... so I don't find how to step in the middle of dropdownlist loading logic... in order to place an `if` statement checking for the `IsSystem` flag and getting the correct text from resource files.

Thanks for any idea on how to handle this...

**EDIT:**

**Controller code:**

`ViewBag.idTaskType = new SelectList(db.TaskTypes, "idTaskType", "Name");`

where `db` is Context from EntityFramework

**View Code:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("idTaskType", String.Empty)
```

Comment: Please post the code where you fill your DropDownList data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am imagining your "TaskTypes" tables as below

```
idTaskType  Name
----------  -----
1           Task1
2           Task2
3           Task3
```

Let us consider two different "App_GlobalResources"

[1]en-US

```
Name    Value
----    -----
Task1   Create  
Task2   Update
Task3   Delete
```

[1]sv

```
Name    Value
----    -----
Task1   Skapa
Task2   Uppdatera
Task3   Ta bort
```

Now develop a IEnumerable SelectListItem

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TaskTypeList { 
        get{
            List<TaskTypes> List = db.TaskTypes.ToList();
            return List.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = x.idTaskType.ToString(), 
                        Text = (HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Task", x.Name)).ToString()
                    });
        } 
    }
```

Finally use

```
@Html.DropDownList("idTaskType", new SelectList(Model.TaskTypeList, "Value", "Text"), String.Empty)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have internationalized versions of your data.  So, you could do something like this:

```
ViewBag.idTaskType = new SelectList(db.TaskTypes
   .Where(x => x.language == "en"), "idTaskType", "Name");
```

Comment: It is not my current scenary... as I need to translate only the TaskTypes that have the flag IsSystem in true... other values need to remain as the user enter it.  But I think I should add some LINQ logic into it.

Comment: @Romias - I don't understand what you mean.  Just add the isSystem check to the linq query.

Comment: I don't have the translation in the database... the TaskType table only has "Name" and "IsSystem". When the TaskType is own by a user, the Name should stay the same... but if the TaskType is buildin (owned by the system) the Name property need to be replaced with a translation that cames from resource files.

Comment: @Romias - It's kind of silly to put one translation in the database, and one in a resource file.  Typically resource files store their strings with ID's, so you'll need some way to map the original string to an id, then look it up in the resource file, then add them to the SelectList.  It's really a poor design to have some of your data pulled from a database and some from a resource file.

Comment: It depends... that table will have 5-10 items builtin (marked as IsSystem)... the other hundreds of items will be user data with no need to translate. So, adding columns in db table to handle translation of 10 items is an overkill. That is why I ended up with this design.